# String function returns seg fault

Tags: c, arrays, string, segmentation-fault

I currently have a function that takes user input in the form of a char array. I'm attempting to parse the input through the functions used below, as well as allocated memory to the pointers used. however, the input I'm expecting from the user is two characters "ab" and a space followed by an integer. When I attempt to convert the it to an integer, the program proceeds to seg fault. I've tried allocating more memory, changing the size of the array, any help would be much appreciated!

```
    int input(char input[10])
    {
        int val;
        char *firstW,*secondW;

        firstW = malloc(sizeof(10));
        secondW = malloc(sizeof(10));

        firstW = strtok(input," ");
        firstW = strstr(input,"ab");
        secondW = strtok(NULL, " ");

        val = atoi(secondW);

//When atoi is called, secondW contains any integer for instace "10", but of course as a string type
//trying to convert string to integer, but returns seg fault
```

Comment: Where is secondW declared?  What is in it when you call atoi?

Comment: You never check `secondW != NULL`.

Comment: If `input` originates from a string literal, that may be the problem --- `strtok` modifies `input` (and modifying a string literal is undefined behavior). On a side-note, the `malloc`s for `firstW` and `secondW` are redundant --- `strtok` returns a pointer into (modified) `input`.

Comment: When using a value of 10 for secondW, and printing it using (mvprintw), the value is printed to the screen, so I don't think it is null.

Answer (score 0):

`malloc(sizeof(10))` is probably a mistake.  It does not allocate 10 bytes, but it allocates enough bytes to hold an `int`.  Depending on your computer's architecture, that is probably 4 or 8 bytes.  Instead you want `malloc(10)`, when you initialize `firstW` and `secondW`.

Comment: Certainly a mistake. But the code actually never uses that value. The pointer is immediately overwritten with the return value of `strtok`/`strstr`